# ModelSim on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, modelsim

I just installed the latest version of ModelSim on Ubuntu 16.04.1. But I can't launch the software by using this command `./vsim`. It always said

> bash: ./vsim: No such file or directory

Can anybody help? Thanks.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

This is most probably because you have a 64-bit system, but vsim is a 32-bit binary. Try the following (from https://askubuntu.com/a/454452):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

This did the trick for me on Debian Stretch, might help you too.

Comment: I also needed libxft2:i386 libxext6:i386

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you haven't set up your `PATH` environment variable correctly. You need to add the directory that `vsim` is in to your `PATH` system variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/intelFPGA_lite/17.0/modelsim_ase/linuxaloem/
```

The PATH variable is a list of directories where the operating system is expecting to find executable commands.

Then test to see if this works. Now, you need to make this change permanent. Edit the `.bash_profile` file in your home directory. You will probably see that there are already additions to the `PATH` variable. You need to add the change you just tested.